# Sumproduct nested inside countifs

Tags: excel-formula

Am trying hard to crack this excel formula but need help. Basically I need count of all "p" & "f" on from different column ranges+rows (Status 1-4), if one the corresponding row value (Site) is "CH". Here is what the data looks like.

```
Status 1    Status 2    Status 3    Status 4    Site
P   f   n   t   CH
P   f   n   t   DL
P   P   P   P   BD
f   f   P   P   CR
f   f   f   f   CH
P   P   f   f   DL
P   P   P   P   BD
t   t   t   t   CR
t   t   t   t   CH
P   f   n   t   DL
P   f   P   f   BD
P   f   P   f   CR
P   P   P   P   CH
```

Any quick help will be much appreciated. I tried formula - `=Countif(E2:E14,"CH",SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:D14,{"p","f"})))`, of course I knew that's wrong!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine several countifs that have OR conditions and sum them all up, for example like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$14,"CH",A2:A14,{"p","f"}),COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$14,"CH",B2:B14,{"p","f"}),COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$14,"CH",C2:C14,{"p","f"}),COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$14,"CH",D2:D14,{"p","f"}))
```

You don't specify the expected result, but according to your written logic, it should be 10 and the formula returns just that.

Comment: Yes, this definitely works Thanks a ton. But was looking for a more compact formula if possible, because similar data has to be pulled up from multiple sheet tabs. If all put together, it will become huge, that's one thing I want to avoid. Can we have something in array or similar approach, Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. As much as I like to avoid INDIRECT, sometimes it is necessary.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(E2:E999, "CH", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, ROW(1:4), 4, 1)&":"&ADDRESS(999, ROW(1:4), 4, 1)), {"f","p"}))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked great, highly appreciate both of you Teylyn & Jeeped